# Getting the values of a casted object to array in one line in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, casting

I have an object which has several nameless objects within it that I need to parse. To address this I had to cast to an array multiple times at different points while traversing it. In my localhost environment, which runs PHP7 in a windows machine, I traversed the object then casted it to an array when needed and called out the index of the variables I knew were there and then casted to an array again, all in one line.

```
$item = ((array)((array)$items[$x])['row'][0]);
```

This approach caused PHPStorm to label it as an error but worked fine in the browser. However, once I took this code to my live environment which is running PHP Version 5.3.29 on an Amazon Linux environment. I got:

[server] is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

However, once I changed the code by splitting the casts into different lines it worked just fine.

```
$item = (array)$items[$x];
$item = (array)$item['row'][0];
```

**My question is**: Why does the first method work on my localhost environment but crashes the page once taken to a live environment? I searched the released notes of PHP7 as I though it was likely a newer feature since PHPStorm labels it as an error, but couldn't find anything that addresses this.

as a side note, I also have the following extension enabled in my localhost:

- extension=php_curl.dll
- extension=php_mbstring.dll
- extension=php_mysqli.dll
- extension=php_openssl.dll
- extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
- extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
- extension=php_sqlite3.dll

Comment: Why are you developing on a PHP7 box if you're deploying to a production box running 5.3.29? Develop on a box that matches the production environment.... that's what virtual boxes are for

Comment: Its was more of an exercise not something that is supposed to go to production. However, I do understand what you mean.

Comment: The problem is that you're using a PHP feature called "array dereferencing" that was only introduced in PHP 5.4

Comment: Thats it! Thank you for that, now I can easily research it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Mark, upgrading PHP to 5.4 will allow you to use your single line example:

```
$item = ((array)((array)$items[$x])['row'][0]);
```